# Как правильно: ткань просвечивается или ткань просвечивает?

Tags: грамотная-речь

Как будет правильно: ткань просвечивается или ткань просвечивает по отношению к прозрачной ткани?

Answer (score 1):

Ответ исправлен.

Основной вариант: ***Основная ткань просвечивает (виднеется) сквозь прозрачную ткань*** (пункт 3 из словаря).

**ПРОСВЕЧИВАТЬ**, 2. только 3 л. **Светиться** сквозь что-л. **Солнце** просвечивает сквозь тучи. **Луна** просвечивает через шторы. 3. только 3 л. **Виднеться** сквозь что-л. Сквозь тучи просвечивает голубое небо. Сквозь рубашку просвечивает голое тело. 5. только 3 л. **Пропускать сквозь себя свет, казаться прозрачным.** Занавески просвечивают. Капроновая юбка просвечивает.

Разговорный вариант: ***Основная ткань просвечивается (виднеется). Основная ткань просвечивается (виднеется) сквозь прозрачную ткань.***

ПРОСВЕЧИВАТЬСЯ,  . 2. **Разг. =Просвечивать (2-5 зн.).** На макушке просвечивается лысина. Сквозь тюлевые занавески просвечивается солнечный зайчик.

Answer (score 1):

Правильно: материал (ткань) просвечивает через прозрачную ткань.

Просвечивать - светиться сквозь что-нибудь, виднеться сквозь что-нибудь. Это словарь.

`Солнце просвечивает через шторы.`

`Сквозь верхушки деревьев просвечивает небо.`

`Сквозь занавеску просвечивает свет лампы.`

`Сквозь рубашку просвечивает голое тело.`

(Все примеры из словарей.)

Просвечивать может источник света (то, что виднеется) через прозрачную ткань. А сама прозрачная ткань при этом просвечивается.